# How to compute $X \omega (Y)$

Tags: differential-geometry

This question is from the book Analysis and Algebra on Differential manifolds by Gadea and Masque and page number is 85.

In this question,I am not able to compute $X \omega (Y)$ or $ Y \omega (X)$.  I am clear with rest of computations.

Can you please help me with the any of them?

[image]

Comment: Compute $\omega(Y)$, thanks to the explicit form of $\omega$ and of $Y$. You end up with a function $f  = \omega(Y)$. Then, take its derivative in the direction of $X$, that is $X\omega(Y) = Xf = df(X)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First work out $\omega(Y)$:

$$\left((x^2+2y)\mathrm{d}x +(x+y^2)\mathrm{d}y\right)\left(y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right) = xy + y^3$$

Now find $X\omega(Y)$:

$$\left(x\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + 2xy\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)(xy+y^3) = xy + 2x^2y+6xy^3$$
For $Y\omega(X)$ find $\omega(X)$ and then $Y\omega(X)$ in the same way.